# Short comic/one shot of a man trying out evil for the first time by kidnapping and murdering a girl, then realizes evil is not for him?

Tags: identification-request, comics

I have a vague memory of a short comic I read once that involved a man talking about how you can't really despise evil without at least trying it first. Therefore, they kidnapped and tortured a girl, committing an irredeemable evil act in order to test their theory. After experiencing evil for the first time, they realized it wasn't for them and lived the rest of their life doing good. That was the gist of it as I remember it, at least.

The story was quite interesting/haunting for me at the time, but it's been years since then and I can't seem to track it down. My earliest memory of it is that I stumbled upon it while reading Grant Morrison's Animal Man run. I don't know if it was a one-shot included in the publication, or something from the same author. It did have that same late 80s-early 90s art style as Animal Man, so the two could be related. I attempted to track this down by looking up terms such as "Grant Morrison" or "Animal Man" with the description of the story, but only ended up with Evil Superman quotes instead. Not sure where to go from there, so I'd appreciate any help in that regard.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this story?

Comment: None at all. It is played as a realistic story of the man (the narrator) describing his process of abducting a girl and hiding her underneath his basement where he proceeded to torture her. There were no supernatural, fantasy or sci-fi elements in the story and the entire comic was described more as a thought experiment.